# If a bond issuer defaults, what do I get back?

Tags: bonds

Say I own a bond with some principal, coupons, and amortizations (i.e. not necessarily a bullet bond).

If at some point before maturity the issuer defaults, I've heard of people saying "recovery rate" and throw around numbers like 40 % but … 40 % **of what?**

40 % of the bond price as of the default date?

40 % of the current principal?

40 % of the current principal + all the missing coupons?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the recovery rate is a fraction of the **face value**, since that's what you get paid back when the bond expires.

Answer (score 0):

This [Investopedia article](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/recovery-rate.asp) explains what recovery rate is:

> Recovery rate is the extent to which principal and accrued interest on defaulted debt can be recovered, expressed as a percentage of face value. The recovery rate can also be defined as the value of a security when it emerges from default or bankruptcy.